# Vibration feel on pedals

Tags: chain, derailleur-rear, chainring, sprocket, vibration

For a while, I am having a vibration feeling (and actually it vibrates) through my feet from chain. It is not because of front derailleur, I have just aligned them. There are no problems with rear derailleur and it shifts pretty good just sometimes I have to push the downshift lever more to engage bigger one. I tested it while not sitting it and applied force with my hands so feeling was lower but I could see chain vibrates vertically. Also RD's arm moving forward to backwards a little but it can be normal I guess. I can hear some friction noise where chain engages to gear like on RD, chainring and cassette. Sound is like sand or dust sandwiched by two pieces of metal.

RD: Altus M2000
FD: Altus M370
Cassette: SHIMANO CS-HG201 (9S) (11-34 T)
Chainset: SHIMANO FC-M371-L (48-36-26T)

Added video:

Comment: Have you checked your bottom bracket?  In my experience a primary cause of pedal vibration is worn or damaged BB bearings.

Comment: Yes, My BB is just changed and probably the problem is not caused by it. I uploaded a video if you can check.

Comment: Did this start AFTER the BB was changed?  Like just after?  I'm not a big fan of coincidence.

Comment: Is the chain binding up?  Perhaps because it's worn or not properly lubricated?  It's hard to tell from the video.

Comment: Changed BB like 2 months ago and I'm sorry but I don't remember it was there before changing BB. It was greased and reinstalled 5 days ago and problem was there before that.

Comment: Where chain starts to engage gears, It rubs to next bigger sprocket. Could be because of RD alignment? Or how BB could affect this? Bike is 17 months old and seems to not worn but I am not an expert. From video I highlighted the sound coming when it rubs so this is only thing I am sure.

Comment: If the chain starts climbing the next sprocket but then drops down to the current sprocket it’s definitely not good. Make sure the chain runs smoothly in the current sprocket without a tendency to “shift” to neighboring sprockets. Look at it from behind, derailleur pulley wheels and chain should be aligned with the center of the sprocket. You’ll probably have to adjust the rear derailleur. If you can’t get it right it’s probably because of cable friction or a bent derailleur hanger.

Comment: Chain doesn't wants to climb bigger ones, It only rubs and makes a vibration. I mean it touches bigger ones little bit. Upshifts are good (considering it has an entry-level Altus derailleur), and downshifts wants little more tension on the lever when changing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be one or more of a number of things depending on events and recent maintenance. Unfortunately the video is too shakey to be much use, but based on the history described in the question and its the comments - I believe the most likely causes are as below:

0. New bottom bracket problem - check it's spinning correctly.
1. The gear indexing has gone out of tune as the cables on what is a new'ish bike have bedded in.

In terms of indexing; for all of the gears between the lowest and highest gears on the cassette the RD's pulley wheels should be directly below the gear that's been selected. The chain should be centered on the sprockets and it should not be rubbing against either the lower gear behind or threatening to drop to a higher gear in front. I would double check this, if in any doubt Park Tools (amongst others) are an excellent resource for advice.

2. The chain is not servicable.

Worn out - use a chain checker to make sure it's okay. In most cases a worn chain would not be a noticabe problem until either the cassette or chainring are changed because the components wear together. But it worth checking as at the extreme end of the wear range it can cause issues.

Non-articulating link - take the chain off the front chain ring and individually flex each of the links to make sure they articulate freely. Look out for twisted links that might have been caused by chain dropping. Links that have rusted, dried or gunged up. If the links aren't articulating correctly; clean, re-lube and work links until they do articulate freely. If it's twisted then unfortunately it's likely a new chain time.

3. Replaced chain too late or kept old chain but swapped in new chainring and/or cassette

It's not mentioned in the question and the chain in video doesn't look new. But, for completeness it's worth mentioning that chain, chainring and a cassette tend to wear together. Adding a new chain to old cassette and chainring can cause issues. As can trying to use new cassettes and  chainrings with old chains. Check chain wear regularly to avoid problems when using new chain. Only ever swap in cassettes and chainrings when the chain has no, or very little wear on it.

4. Bent derallieur hanger

If the bike has been dropped or otherwise impacted on the RD then it's possible that the hanger has been bent putting the RD alignment out. In my experience it doesn't take much out of alignment to make it impossible to get the gears to index correctly.

[Derailleur Alignment Guide tools](https://www.parktool.com/product/derailleur-hanger-alignment-gauge-dag-2-2) to check and fix this can be purchased, but are quite expensive. At a push it's possible just to try fitting a new hanger to see if that improves things, but unfortunately it's not unknown for new hangers to be out, so this check might just be one of those things where it is best to just take into a shop for.

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I was riding 2020 Cube 400 Nature eBike and the chain (KMC X9) vibration through to the pedals from brand new, day one, was so bad I didn’t want to ride. Seller '99Bikes' mechanics repeatedly said they felt nothing. After around 8months of frustration, I took the bike to a different outfit who took some measurements and then placed a washer between the frame and the derailleur which greatly improved the ride. After two years, the chain was replaced by a third outfit and the vibration immediately disappeared completely. It was like, ‘so this is what the perfect ride is like’, beautiful for an entire year. Recently purchased a 2022 Cube Stereo 120P (demonstrator), beaut ride but the gears slipped sometimes because of a damaged chain (Shimano CN-M6100). Chain was replaced and now an identical vibration is present. My evaluation is a loose or stretched chain is causing the vibration. Bike mechanics take only a very short a test ride, if at all, often only within a carpark; not nearly long enough.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  In essence your answer is that an old or worn chain can cause this?  But you said it also happened with a new chain?  Can you clarify exactly what your diagnosis is, and how you resolved it?